# after power failure: get Server auth dir /daemon/ServerAuthDir is set to , but dosent exist

Tags: server

After a power failure, on re-starting UBUNTU linix, get message: "gdm server auth dir (daemon/ServAuthDir) is set to /var/lib/gdm but it dosen't exist". the directory IS  there, but it  doesn't start volume manager properly, complains HALD is not running and stops at a single command line. I have been trying to find out how to fix this for many months. can long-in as single user and startx , but no volumes apart from hard disks are found. Familiar with UNIX but not as good on LINIX. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After months of not knowing  how to fix this I looked at the web-page:

http://projects.gnome.org/gdm/docs/2.14/controlling.html

which gave a lot of advice, and I had already set `chmod 755` for the directory `/var/lib/gdm`... and associated files.

(use:  `ls -lsa` to list all the files starting .(dot) ).

I looked through the notes to try various things, but starting the gnome ONCE from a bash as root.

```
sudo gdm start
```

seems to mean it is now always started at each boot.

So that seems to have fixed it. (There are quite a few other websites requesting a solution, this seems to make the files needed) and it creates  file `.gdminfo` which I think it was looking for.